# In correspondence, what is the correct way to refer to two people with the same first name but different last names?

Tags: grammar

I have received an email containing the following statement, "tell John Ford and Smith that their proposal is due". As both individuals share the same first name, what should the correct directive state ?

Comment: The correct way to refer to two people is to refer to each of them exactly like you would refer to each of them separately. Whether or not they share the first name, or the first letter, the middle initial, or the title, is completely and utterly irrelevant. If you would never call John Smith simply "Smith", then it's quite obviously rude to simply call him "Smith" here. "Tell John Ford and Smith" means that you habitually refer to John Smith as simply "Smith". And for what it's worth, I think all of that is general reference or really just common sense.

Comment: You can factor out family names, but not given names.

Comment: You could call them "the Johns" the way the characters of Bob Slydell and Bob Porter were referred to simply as "the Bobs" in [Office Space](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nV7u1VBhWCE).

Comment: Welcome to the site! As the others have said, you would normally have to write both names in full. Only when they have the same surname would you leave anything out (Mark and John Smith).